# Saves nil for daterange for same date Rails 4.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date-range

I am using
Rails : 4.2.7 and
Postgress : 9.3

Migration

```
def change
  create_table :category do |t|
    t.float :price
    t.daterange :date_range
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

When I am trying to save date_range with same date

```
from = Date.today.beginning_of_day
to = Date.today.end_of_day 

Category.create(date_range: from..to)
```

saves `nil` for `date_range`.

Its work perfectly if dates are different like

```
from = Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day
to = Date.today.end_of_day
```

One solution is create separate columns from and to.

Comment: What is the field type of `date_range` field. ?

Comment: field type is daterange.

Answer (score 1):

Dateranges only operates on dates, that is your beginning of day and end of day will both be truncated to `today` which creates an empty range (which apparently is translated as `nil`)

What you most likely mean is to use Date.today (inclusive) to Date.tomorrow (exclusive)

If you actually want to store the times you should use a tsrange.

Comment: Sorry for not actually knowing the rails terminology :/